# How can I auto-insert a comment header in Coda?

Tags: comments, text-editor, coda

Whenever I create a new file, I would like to be able to include a comment header that has me as the author and some copyright info. How can I automatically generate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "Clip". A clip is basically a pre-defined snippet of code that can be quickly inserted.

The Clips button is along the bottom of the Coda window next to "Hints".

Clips make it really easy to insert a block of code quickly (like `<!Doctype ...>`).